# Components for a motor driving a generator

Tags: power, diodes

I have a small set up of two 12 volt motors and a belt to connect them.

The first motor is run off of 12V and the second one is driven by the belt between, creating a generator that puts out 120V. It will actually run a few lights but nothing that draws serious amperage.

I want to add a couple of capacitors so I would only have to jump start the first motor to start and then run from current being produced.

I know I'll need a diode and couple of capacitors.

What size diode and capacitors would I need?

The first motor is an old drill motor and the second run by the belt (the "generator") is one out of a printer.

Comment: Are you hoping to run the first motor from the output of the generator?  If so, you need to look into [perpetual motion machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) and why they don't work.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? - "I know I'll need a diode and couple of capacitors."

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a perpetual motion machine with a motor and a generator - it won't work.

People who think this are often thinking about the mechanics at a very basic level: they think "it spins and makes electricity" and "it takes electricity and spins" but the mechanics of spinning are actually a bit more intricate than "it spins or it doesn't"

Spinning involves speed, and torque (spinning force). The more electrical current you take from a generator the more torque is needed to make it keep spinning. The more torque you need a motor to make, the more current it requires.

You used a belt to make the generator spin faster than the motor, but this also makes the motor apply more force than the generator needs, so the total power, which is speed times torque, is about the same - a bit like an electrical transformer keeps the electrical power, which is current times voltage, about the same.

If you try to power the motor from the generator, no matter how you do it it won't keep turning, it will slow down on its own because the generator produces less current than the motor needs to keep the generator turning. It's like connecting two axles together with *two* belts and then hoping one belt will keep the other one turning.

Sorry.

If that is *not* what you're trying to do, then please explain the question better.